# Reading parameters from txt file in Forms skipping empty lines

Tags: c#, forms

I have to read some parameters from a txt file and then use them in my Windows Forms application.

The txt file looks like this:

```
[Parameter1]
1
[Parameter2]
1000
[Parameter3]
5
[Parameter4]
0
```

I've been searching for the right solution on the Internet, but didn't find one. The point is to achieve these points: 
1. There can be empty lines (for example 5 empty lines between 1 and [Parameter2] in the txt file and the app needs to load those parameters anyway. 
2. If the txt file misses any of these parameters, the app needs to load existing ones and then I'll attribute the missing ones with default values.

Code in my app:

```
if (File.Exists("path.txt"))
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("path.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    string linia;
    while ((linia = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string a = string.Empty;
        string b = string.Empty;
        string c = string.Empty;
        string LogLevelstring = string.Empty;

        if (string.Compare(linia, "[Parameter1]") == 0)
            a = sr.ReadLine();
        if (string.Compare(sr.ReadLine(), "[Parameter2]") == 0)
            b = sr.ReadLine();                          
        if (string.Compare(sr.ReadLine(), "[Parameter3]") == 0)
            c = sr.ReadLine();
        if (string.Compare(sr.ReadLine(), "[Parameter4]") == 0)
            LogLevelstring= sr.ReadLine();
    }
    fs.Close();
    sr.Close();
}
```

This function loads line by line. When the .txt file is correct, it works, but when it has any of things i pointed above, it doesn't work.

Any help and code samples would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Compare `linia` to `string.Empty` or use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: You could remove all new lines and carriage returns e.g. `string.Replace("\n\r", string.Empty);`. Also, I'd use regex to parse the parameters out..

Comment: You can use File.ReadAllLines instead reading one by one and remove empty lines from string array you got by ReadAllLines method. Now resultant array is without empty lines. You can refactor the logic you have to use this new string array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Regular Expresions using the Regex class to filter each row. It can shorten youre code a lot. If you need help to build youre regex try this website : https://regex101.com/.

Hope this helps :D
Jasper.